# Does linearity require a field, ring, or group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Given any set $S$, a function $f : S^n \to S^m$ is linear iff for all $a, b \in S, x, y \in S^n, f(ax+by) = af(x) + b(y)$.  This presupposes, of course, that addition and scalar multiplication in $S$ are defined.  What requirements do we impose on these operations? Must they constitute a field? A ring?  Since different definitions of addition and multiplication may be valid and result in fields, are there functions which are linear in *any* field definition, or are we always talking implicitly about a specific, fixed field?

Thinking about it further, the question as posed may be trivial, because we've only defined linearity, but haven't given it any significance.  Does the definition below tighten things:

Given a set $F$ of functions from $S^n \to S^m$, $L$ is the subset of $F$ such that:

1. $f, g \in F \implies f \circ g \in F$
2. There is a one-to-one correspondence between elements of $L$ and *matrices*, a matrix defined as $n \cdot m$ values from $S$.

What restrictions on addition and multiplication are necessary for that definition to work? To allow standard matrix multiplication to implement the functions? To allow composition to be implemented as matrix multiplication?

Comment: In the first line you have a definition of linearity for $f: S^n \to S^m$. What is $S$? Also, I assume you meant $bf(y)$ not $b(y)$.

Comment: $S^n$ is usually used to denote the $n$-sphere. Is that what you're referrring to? It doesn't seem to be the case from the rest of the question.

Comment: Also, your second condition of "one-to-one correspondence" between $L$ and matrices is way too broad since you do not specify the details of this bijection. The only thing this imposes is that the two sets have the same cardinality. If $S$ is infinite, this is basically trivial.

Comment: I'm curious if you can drop some really basic conditions (associativity, closure) and the construction to translate between linear maps and matrices would still work

Answer (score 3):

The most general context over which linear algebra is usually done is in that of modules over a ring. Let $R$ be a ring (commutative, with unity), and $M$ be a set endowed with operations of scalar multiplication $R\times M\to M$ and addition $+: M\times M\to M$. If these operations are nice and compatible with all the usual properties of associativity, commutativity, distributivity, existence of identity, etc. then $M$ is said to be a *module* over $R$.

If $M$ and $M'$ are modules over a ring $R$ then a map $f: M\to M'$ is said to be *linear* if $f(ax+by)=af(x)+bf(y)$ for all $x,y\in M$ and $a,b\in R$.